# how to apply join with two columns on a single table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables as following,

```
USER                         
id     name                
================            
1      user1                 
2      user2
3      user3                 

DETAILS 
value    created_by   updated_by 
===================================
abc         1             2 
def         1             3
```

is it possible to apply join in such a way that my resulting structure looks like,

```
QUERY RESULT

DETAILS.value    USER.created_by   USER.updated_by 
========================================================
abc                     user1             user2 
def                     user1             user3
```

Comment: Hint: Join Details table with user table twice; once using created_by, and then using updated_by. Now, as Strawberry said, try to figure out the query and edit the question with your latest attempt based on this hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 of the methods is to join table twice -

```
SELECT D.value `DETAILS.value`, U.name `USER.created_by`, U2.name `USER.updated_by`
FROM DETAILS D
JOIN USER U ON D.created_by = U.id
JOIN USER U2 ON D.updated_by = U2.id
```